# Getting [Object Object] in Template with *ngFor Angular

Tags: angular

My data keeps appearing as [Object Object] in my HTML template when I do my *ngFor loop.

Here is my view with the data enumerated in the developer console:

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

[image]

Lastly, my TS code:

[image]

Also, when I iterate through "company.name" as such:

[image]

I get:

[image]

I'm storing the response from the server in the "companyResults" variable that I get when my "getCompany()" function is ran.

How do I get my data in string format?

Edit:

After looping through the keys, this is what they were:

[image]

Comment: I have updated my answer to use Observable try it out and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is something like:

```html
<mat-option..
  {{company.name}}
</mat-option>
```

You need to select a field in that object.

Update:

```js
nameField = "2. name";

//constructor(...){}...
```

```html
<mat-option..
  {{company[nameField]}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: I did do that initially, and it's my mistake for not posting the photo of me doing that first. However, when I choose the company name property, I get nothing. I get "undefined".

Comment: ok I'm suspicious that the actual key is `5. name` could you console.log the Object.keys of `this.companyResults`? As in loop the `companyResults` in a for loop and log the keys

Comment: I updated the question. I believe you were right.

Comment: I think you printed the Object.keys of `this.companyResults` but I actually meant the elements of `this.companyResults`; as in loop over `this.companyResults` and print Object.keys of each element inside `this.companyResults`

Comment: I assume this is what you wanted?

Comment: yes! :-) so I was right; the key names are a little different. It is `"2. name"`

Comment: This was so frustrating, so I appreciate your help immensely. Your answer was correct.

Comment: @DaveGuerrero glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML you are printing the whole `company` object instead of only company name.

Replace this

```
{{ company }}
```

with this

```
{{ company?.name }}
```

EDIT: As I read one of your comment that you tried above solution already then here is the updated answer.

P.S: The issue was a wrong company name i.e `2. name` instead of just `name`, however rather than going with those weird names I would parse and create a new array of object with more readable field names.

```
// Declare companies variable as Observable
searchedCompanies$: Observable<any>;

getCompany(value: any) {
 // Do not subscribe here but return the Observable response
 this.searchedCompanies$ = this.searchCompanyService.searchCompanies(value)
 .pipe(map((result) => result.bestMatches.map(company => ({
    symble: company['2. symble'],
    name: company['2. name'],
    type: company['3. type'],
    region: company['4. region']
   ...
 })
)))
```

and in template subscribe the Observable by `async` pipe

```
Use async pipe to subscribe and read the data 
<mat-option *ngFor="let company of searchedCompanies$ | async"
  {{company?.name}}
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result as before with the data appearing as "undefined".

Comment: @DaveGuerrero I would parse the result and create a new array with more readable field names check the answer, also I would strongly recommend you to not subscribe Observable in component but use async pipe like above example, this will unsubscribe automatically and prevent memory leak.